# createElement set HTML tag conditionally React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this:

```
const Component = React.createElement(props.type ? "p" : "div", {
    className: "fff"
})
```

How do I set HTML tag conditionally (one line)?

Or, if its possible, right inside JSX (something like that):

```
<props.type ? "p" : "div" />
```

Comment: Why does it need to be conditional at that level? Why not make the condition one level higher and do `{props.type ? <p /> : <div />}`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jsx then I would just recommend doing it in your component.

```
const Component = (props) => {
  const content = // whatever content you want

  return props.type ? (
    <p>
      {content}
    </p>
  ) : (
    <div>
      {content}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This will conditionally return what you want, you can do all sorts of stuff with this kind of syntax and at this level.

Or if it's not a specific component and just in code, the same thing applies.

```
{props.type ? (
  // code for <p>
) : (
  // code for <div>
)
```

If you have common content, just store that in a const somewhere, and insert it between the tags.

Comment: I just need to change the `tag` conditionally, without changing/dup element's props that I'm passing with it

Comment: Yep, that's basically how it's done. You need the closing tag for conditionally rendering elements. If it's a self closing el then `props.type ? <p /> : <div />` is fine and you can spread your props into each of them. `<p {...props} /> : <div {...props} />`. Avoid duping by writing the internals once, `<p>{contentEls}</p> : <div>{contentEls}</div>`

Comment: how do I convert all element's props that I'm passing with it? It is quite a list, and it has many dependables, functions, etc. (from JSX format to what you are suggesting)

Comment: What do you mean by "convert all element's props"? Do you have an example with more detail? Or can you describe the reason you're trying to do this?